# page not found error django registration

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I am using django-registration with default url-configurations. when I point to url mysite/accounts/register I am able to see the registration form but when I click submit button it keeps processing for some time and then returns "Page not found error". although If I try the same on development server at localhost it is working fine. I am checking e-mails at localhost by firing python's mail server. Here are settings for production server

```
    ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 465
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com' 
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

and here are settings for development server at localhost

```
    ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
    EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
    EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

I am using default urls configuration,

```
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

am I missing some configuration/settings? any help would be appreciated .